# Detect UITableview header reaches at bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In `UITableview` how to detect if the last header reached at the bottom while scrolling. Cells will not be display initially. It will show only if the user touches the header.

I have used this delegate to get if the cell reaches the bottom,

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

but I can't get it for headers. Is there any way to detect?

[image]

All answers are appreciated!!

Comment: you have only header in tableview ? and how many tableview header you have and tell me that hight of tableview ?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya I did it by using scrollViewDidScroll:

Comment: Try checking `contentOffset.y` in `scrollViewDidScroll` and if it is equal to the total height of the `contentSize`, maybe that will help!

Comment: In general, the bottom of any scroll view content touches the bottom of the view when the `contentSize.height - bounds.size.height == contentOffset.y`.  For this question, it sounds like the contentSize height is just the sum of the header heights.  (Also, I notice you've never marked an answer correct, ever).